# How hard is it to get rare 18 year old Scotches directly in Scotland?

Tags: scotch

For the purpose of definition we'll call 'rare 18 year old Scotch' bottles that aren't really common in foreign markets like Canada.

What I wonder is, if we're talking about that type of high-grade Scotch, how easy is it to find a bottle if you were visiting distilleries or liquor stores in Scotland directly.

In other words, when distilleries produce premium product does it tend to mostly stay in country, or are some of these whiskies just produced in such low quantities that getting your hands on it anywhere is rare?

Comment: It's incredibly easy to shop old Whiskey from Scotland and Ireland. I never had a problem finding old bottles in a well sorted store here in Germany; and if they don't happen to have them, you can always order online on amazon or at a whiskey reseller. If you need some links, I can give them to you.

Comment: A friend of mine in Naples says his corner shop sold even rarer ones, like the Octomore!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an avid whisky fan, and having worked in a distillery and visited most Scottish distilleries, I can tell you this:

It's incredibly easy - pretty much all the distilleries have 18 year old single malts. It's not rare at all, in fact I don't think I'd class them as "premium" in that way. For many of the whiskies I like I'll buy the 12, 15 and 18 year old. Amusingly enough, many of these whiskies are also available in supermarkets and even local shops.

There are a few I'll hunt down that are considerably older, but they really do command a premium. These are the kind that usually go to collectors, or are available through specialist groups, such as the [Scotch Malt Whisky Society](https://www.smws.com/).

If your question is because you plan on a whisky tour and you want to know if you can find these whiskies in the distilleries, then yes - no problem.

Comment: Gah, I'm jealous. Send me a bottle?